# How to set class attribute on vuejs functional component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vuejs functional component that mimics a div behavior. To do so, I set it's class based on the props that it receives.

Something like this:

```
<MyDiv textAlign="left">Div with left aligned text</MyDiv>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="text-left">Div with left aligned text</div>
```

However, if MyDiv component is the root element for some other component, like:

Card.vue

```
<template>
  <MyDiv display="inline-block" textAlign="center">
    <slot />
  </MyDiv>
</template>
```

And if Card receive any class attribute when used, I can't set the class attribute value based on MyDiv props, instead, class (on MyDiv) is overridden by the class received by Card.

So this:

```
<Card class="cool-style">Card content</Card>
```

Becomes:

```
<div class="cool-style">Card content</div>
```

Ant not this (what I need):

```
<div class="cool-style inline-block text-center">Card content</div>
```

Here's MyDiv component:

MyDiv.vue

```
export default {
  name: 'my-div',
  functional: true,
  props: {
    textAlign: {
      type: String,
      allowed: ['left', 'right', 'center'],
      default: null
    },
    display: {
      type: String,
      allowed: ['hidden', 'block', 'inline-block', 'flex'],
      default: null
    }
  },
  render: function(createElement, context) {
    let classes = [];

    // Adds parent class to itself
    if (typeof context.data.staticClass == 'string') {
      classes.push(context.data.staticClass);
    }

    let classes = classes.concat([
      'my-div',
      context.props.textAlign && `text-${context.props.textAlign}`,
      context.props.display && context.props.display
    ]);

    classes = classes.filter(elm => elm != null);
    classes = classes.join(' ').trim();

    return createElement(
      props.type,
      {
        attrs: {
          class: classes
        }
      },
      context.children
    );
  }
};
```

---

**TL;DR**

How can I force my custom class to a vue functional component, when it's parent have already a class being set?

As a side note, it can be done using statefull (non-functional and regular) components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
attrs: {
  class: classes
}
```

by

```
class: classes
```

Side note: Not really needed to join the array into a string, you can pass the array.